# Как настроить роутер MicroTik, чтобы сайт на Denwer'е открывался по локальной Wi-Fi сети?

Tags: http, denwer, dns, wifi

Имеется **MikroTik RB941-2nD-TC** (hAP lite 802.11n 300Mbps 2.4ГГц 4xLAN)
У роутера адрес стандартный **192.168.88.1**
Работает Wi-Fi сеть

К роутеру сетевым кабелем подключен ноутбук. На ноутбуке запущен **Denwer**, на котором есть локальный сайт, к примеру **site.loc**. Запуск в браузере **http://site.loc** - на ноутбуке отлично работает (сайт открывается).

К MAC-адресу ноутбука привязан постоянный ip: **192.168.88.5**
В настройках роутера **/webfig/#IP:DNS.Static** добавлена связка вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Брэндмаур на Винде ноутбука попросту отключен. 
В папке сайта **site.loc/www** Denwer'а лежит **.htaccess** в котором написано:

```
# dnwr_ip 192.168.88.5
```

всё по инструкции: [www.denwer.ru/faq/shared.html](http://www.denwer.ru/faq/shared.html)

Как обеспечить доступ к сайту **http://site.loc** с любого устройства (планшета, компьютера, телефона) подключенного к Wi-Fi сети роутера?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть два варианта.

Для любого (почти) роутера.

- настриваем проброс портов.
- заходим на любой сервис бесплатных dns (например, noip.com) и регистрируем себе имя, настраиваем роутер, что бы он обновлял апйи. tplink/asus роутеры это умеют.
- используем это имя и заходим на сервер с любого места.

Но этот способ не работает, если у Вас на роутере локальный внутренний айпи. У меня статический апйи и я этот способ использую по полной для доступа к домашним ресурсам.

Второй способ (и похоже, Вы его описали). mikrotik умеет делать "static dns" - то есть, можно ему подсказать, как резолвить неизвестное имя. Это будет доступно для всех устройств внутри сети, которые приняли настройки днс от роутера (он обычно указывает себя как dns). Подробно о настройке - на [сайте mikrotik](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0:IP/DNS). Если кратко, то Вам в консоли микротика нужно выполнить команду

```
/ip dns static
add name site.loc address=192.168.88.5
```

а [здесь](http://vedernikoff.ru/dns-v-mikrotik/) показан способ через gui.

У этого способа есть один недостаток - если какой то пользователь укажет dns в настройках ручками, то работать он не будет (хотя мало чего там придумали, может оно и фильтрует, но думаю, это маловероятно, но технически реализуемо). Также, я бы переподключил устройства, кеш почистил, мало чего.
Также стоит посмотреть, какие настройки роутер отдает клиентам - какой dns он указывает. Должен указывать себя.

Comment: ваша команда:
"/ip dns static
add name site.loc address=192.168.88.5" полностью повторяет то что я сделал через web-интерфейс

Comment: за изменение dns настроек на телефонах и планшетах я не беспокоюсь - это три страшные неизвестные буквы для тех кто будет пользоваться этим локальным сайтов по Wi-Fi сети. 

Про подключение к Интернету я ни слова не написал, его не будет в данной локальной Wi-Fi сети. 

Но всё равно не работает нифига )

Comment: Тогда остаётся последний вариант - поднять свой DNS server , например, bind.

Comment: на компьютере? 

кстати то что устройства подключенные к данной Wi-Fi сети еще и подключены к Интернету например через 3G как-то влияет это?

Comment: Вполне. Устройство может использовать днс от 3g

Comment: Вот точно! оказалось что я всё правильно делал - всё действительно просто, но тестировал я на телефоне, и пока в нём не отключил интернет через мобильную связь он не увидел мой локальный домен в локальной Wi-Fi сети

Comment: На самом деле есть простой способ заставить пользователя использовать Ваш ДНС - это зарулить весь трафик на внешний днс с помощью правила redirect на DNS сервер микротика.

Comment: А вот с этого места по подробнее можно пожалуйста? Например, имеем смартфон одновременно подключенный как к мобильному интернету, так и к нашей Wi-Fi сети, которую раздает роутер. Когда на этом смартфоне я набираю http://site.loc - почему запрос к DNS пойдет в локальную Wi-Fi сеть к роутеру а не в мобильный глобальный интернет? Как я могу с помощью настроек роутера дать приоритет DNS'ке роутера?

Comment: Еще раз повторюсь: у локальной Wi-Fi сети нет доступа к Интернету!

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно прописать ваш роутер в качестве DNS сервера на устройствах, с которых вы хотите получать доступ к сайту. Тогда, при запросе на таком устройстве сайта site.loc, устройство обратится за IP адресом к DNS серверу (роутеру), получит от него IP 192.168.88.5 и отправит запрос туда.

Comment: А без прописывания DNS сервера на устройствах никак нельзя? Это же сумасшествие полное, у меня это будут разные мобильные устройства: планшеты, телефоны на iOS и Android.

Comment: @Enshtein: можно и без смены DNS. Но тогда придётся вручную на каждом устройстве прописывать соответствие имени site.loc с нужным IP. Есть и третий вариант - взять реальный домен (можно поддомен) и прописать для него A запись с нужным IP. Сделать это нужно на тех NS, где домен обслуживается. Тогда про то, на каком IP находится домен, можно будет узнать с любого устройства. Ну или ещё вариант - обращаться не по имени, а напрямую по IP.

Comment: а) из Wi-Fi сети не будет доступа к Интернету - я же про Интернет в вопросе ничего не писал
б) в ручную прописать соответствие? как вы себе это представляете сделать на планшете, телефонах ?
в) вариант с обращением по ip - совсем не в тему уже...

Comment: См. выше - я предложил способ через настройку firewall на mikrotik

Answer (score 0):

Убедитесь, что другие устройства получают IP вашего сайта от DNS MikroTik'а. Подключитесь по WiFi с другого ноута и проверьте с помощью команды.

```
nslookup site.loc
```

Вы должны увидеть IP, который вы прописали, а DNS сервером должен выступать MikroTik.
Чтобы понять, точно ли дело в DNS Микротика, пробовали прописать на устройстве, которое подключается во WiFi, в файл hosts запись

```
192.168.88.5 site.loc
```

Подключали второй компьютер проводом? Не работает только через WiFi?
Смотрели в сторону настроек файервола и моста на MikroTik'e? WiFi клиенты друг друга видят?
В winbox есть полезная штука Tools->Torch. Что там у вас показывается, когда пытаетесь обратиться из локалки на ваш сервер?